# Report Type Issue

Tags: reporting, custom-report-type

We have few reports based on one report type (e;g Accounts with Assets and Transaction Header) but weird part is when I try to edit this custom report type; it is not showing up...

but I am able to create reports of this custom report type (Accounts with Assets and Transaction Header)

Has anyone come across this issue before and what is the fix for it so that we can edit this custom report type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure your SFDC Account profile having the system permission "Manage Custom Report Types" which will help to edit custom report types.

> "Manage Custom Report Types" - Create, edit, and delete custom report
> types.

System Permission "Manage Custom Report Types" will require following permission,

> "View Setup and Configuration" - View the App Setup and Administrative
> Settings pages.

and permission"View Setup and Configuration" will require below system permission,

> "View Roles and Role Hierarchy" - View the App Setup and
> Administrative Settings pages.

Please let me know if it helps.